# Retrieving Values from checkout page and redirect other custom page in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am facing problem, how can we take values from checkout page and redirect with these values to different page and then make payment on that page, i have create my own custom checkout page on different website. I just want to take values from checkout page and push them to my other website page and the user can make payment from it.

Could you please share any idea, how's that possible.

Thank you

Comment: I would look into POST or GET requests. Essentially they can help you take a form on page A (your checkout page), and then when you press submit send the values in the form to page B (the payments page).

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, is there any helpful you can provide to me?